# Prism.js highlight only if it begins the line

Tags: javascript, prismjs

I'm writing a custom language extension to Prism.js and have a problem highlighting comments. I want to highlight comments, that begin with either `#` or `//` and start at the beginning of the line:

```
# Example comment
// Example comment
1*2//comment <-- this should not be highlighted
```

Here is the pattern I'm using to detect comments: `/(^|[^\\])[#\/\/].*/`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected:

[image: demo]

I tried using the `lookbehind` and `greedy` options ([docs](https://prismjs.com/extending.html)), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing the regular expression to `/(^|^\\)(\/{2}|#).*/gm`